# Proof of relation between radii in hexagonal packing of 12 circles in a circle

Tags: circles, packing-problem

I have 12 circles of radius r arranged in hexagonal pattern inside a container circle of radius R.

Picture of 12 equal circles packed inside a container circle in hexagonal pattern

[image]

This is not the densest packing, but an expression of the relation between the radii can be evaluated:

$$r = \frac{1}{25}(2\sqrt{21}-3)R$$

I'm looking for a proof of this expression. I tried different ways, trigonometry, symmetries, Pythagoras, secant-tangent theorem, quadrilaterals, but I don't seem to find the right approach. Can someone provide a demonstration or point me to a relevant reference?

Thanks!

Alberto

Comment: It's easier to prove the other way around - set $r=1$ and prove $R=\frac23\sqrt{21}+1$. The $+1$ is the radius of one of the outermost small circles, and $\frac23\sqrt{21}$ is the distance between the centre of the large circle and the centre of one of the outermost small circles.

Comment: Thanks! I see the geometric construction, but why is the distance between the centres $\frac{2}{3}\sqrt{21}$? Sorry, I'm really a beginner here...

Comment: Connect the centres of the three middle circles to form an equilateral triangle with side length 2. The height of that triangle is $\sqrt{3}$. The centre of that triangle (and the centre of the large circle) is at a third of that height, $\sqrt{3}/3$. Apply Pythagoras to a right-angled triangle with that $\sqrt{3}/3$ as one of the legs, and $3$ as the other leg.

Comment: Great! All clear, thanks for the help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

Following on from Jaap’s comments,

Taking the radius of the small circles to be $1$, the radius of the big circle is $a+1$ as shown in the diagram.

The distance $x$ is $\frac23$ of the height of the equilateral triangle formed by the centres of three neighbouring small circles, so $$x=\frac23\sqrt{3}$$

The distance $y$ is the height of the same triangle just referred to, so $$y=\sqrt{3}$$

Now, by Pythagoras, $$a^2=(x+y)^2+1$$
$$\implies a^2=\frac{28}{3}$$
$$\implies a=\frac23\sqrt{21}$$

Hence the large circle has radius $$\frac23\sqrt{21}+1$$